# Case sensitivity of search terms in TweetR package

Tags: r, sttwitterapi, tweetr

I want to know if the search terms in tweetR package to collect tweets through API are case sensitive?
For example search term "Grand Old Party" and "grand old party" would yield entirely similar results, entirely different results ( means case sensitive search terms) or some mix of both based of some other factors.

I have read tweetR help file and also finding if other people asked similar question, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the datasets manually. Search terms are case sensitive. Meaning #Joseph and #joseph in twittR package would give different results.